# Taking address of temporary?

Tags: c++, qt, push, qtimer

I try to to use Push Mode and QTimerEvent of QT to implement a timerEvent. My code returns following error 
"Taking address of temporary". What is wrong? Any help would be appreciated.
Here is the code

```
void Engine::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *)
{
m_audioIODevice->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

const qint64 nBytesReady = m_auidioInput->bytesReady();
m_DataBufer->Push(&m_audioIODevice->read(nBytesReady));

emit BuferChanged(m_DataBufer->GetByteArray());
 }
```

Comment: y not post the error message, u now

Comment: `auto tmp = m_audioIODevice->read(nBytesReady);` `m_DataBufer->Push(&tmp);`

Comment: @FiddlingBits, no, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
m_DataBufer->Push(&m_audioIODevice->read(nBytesReady));
```

is wrong. Function `m_audioIODevice->read(nBytesReady)` returns a temporary object and as the compiler says you may not get the address of a temporary object that is of rvalue. Use some intermediate variable that to keep the result of the function call.

Also it seems that this statement in general is invalid because you are trying to push addresses of temporary objects that will be deleted in the end of the statement execution.

Comment: More details: the temporary object returned by `m_audioIODevice->read()` will be out-of-scope after ` Engine::timerEvent` and be destroyed. So we should new an object to store values returned by `m_audioIODevice->read()`